# Why does this JavaScript function continually add the className on scroll?

Tags: javascript, onscroll

The classname is successfully added when beginning to scroll, but continues to add the class when scrolling.

The classes are removed just fine upon returning to the top of the page.

```
function scrollHeader() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("rbuxApp");
  var y = elmnt.scrollTop;

  if(y >= 4 && document.getElementById("header").className !== "min-header") {
    document.getElementById("header").className += "min-header ";

}
  else {
    document.getElementById("header").className -= "min-header ";
  };
}
```

Comment: Do you already have a class for the element with id "header" before "min-header" was added?

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById("header").className` can have multiple classes in which case your condition for `document.getElementById("header").className !== "min-header"` wont work.

You can split the classes by space and then look if it matches with any item. Also you need to add a space before the classname when you are adding with another class. So better to try it this way.

```
//Get the class names in array
var classNames = document.getElementById("header").className.split(/\s+/);
//Check if your class exists already
if(classNames.indexOf('min-header') !== -1) {
   //If not add the class to the array
   classNames.push('min-header');
   //Now join the classes back with space and set it back to the className property
   document.getElementById("header").className = classNames.join(" ");
}
```

You can follow the same way when you want to remove the class from the element by this way :

```
var index = classNames.indexOf('min-header');
if(index !== -1) {
    classNames.splice(index,1);
    document.getElementById("header").className = classNames.join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are appending to existing class name using `+=`

```
document.getElementById("header").className += "min-header ";
```

Change it to

`document.getElementById("header").className = "min-header "`;

Comment: Noting that that will obliterate every other class that the element has. ;-0

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the line where you add the class name:

```
document.getElementById("header").className += "min-header ";
```

You add "min-header " with a space at the end, but you only check it against "min-header" with no space. So, your element's className will never be equal to just "min-header" with no space, and thus the class gets added over and over again. A much more robust way of doing this is utilizing the `classList` object in an element. Here's some documentation on it: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList`.

You can use `element.classList.add()` to add the class to your element, `element.classList.contains()` to check if it's already on there, and `element.classList.remove()` to take it off of the element.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. element.classList worked for me. Love to know any reasons why this may not be a good way to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: @RyanBrownlow Pls accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks